# PostgreSQL BitRock Installer Hangs

Tags: windows-7, postgresql

While installing PostgreSQL the BitRock installer hangs when it reaches the point that it should copy the files.

There were very few things that came up on search engines for Windows 7, I tried `netsh winsock reset` in DOS without any success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had installed PostgreSQL on my laptop though decided to reattempt doing a custom WAPP stack on my desktop for easier debugging. After numerous instances of attempting to install including a sacrilegious reboot (with everything disabled) I merely copied the files from my laptop to my desktop and the installation then simply overwrote the files instead of hanging at that point.

There are a couple options available if someone does not have a second computer where the installer works. The http://www.postgresql.org/download/windows/ page provides a ZIP download. If for some reason that becomes unavailable and third party mirrors aren't something someone is comfortable with then installing to a ritualized operating system may serve as a more acceptable tertiary option.